# php strtotime and date functions are using different timezones

Tags: php, date, timezone

strtotime is being calculated from 1970-01-01 (UTC) and date is using my timezone i.e America/New_York
A simple example:

Where timestamp is 0:

```
var_dump(date('Y-m-d h:i:s', 0));
```

prints: `1969-12-31 07:00:00`

Where it should return 0, it returns

```
var_dump(strtotime('1969-12-31 07:00:00'));
-43200
```

Now, obviously, I could add the timezone to the date i.e

```
strtotime($date . ' -5')
```

and it'd work.

But, I'm using the `strtotime` function everywhere.

I tried playing with the `_$ENV['TZ']` and the `date_timestamp_get()`; 
But I can't sync them.

I also modified the date.timezone in php.ini to America/New_York and still nothing.

Finally, forcing the timezone using `date_timestamp_set('UTC')`, works fine and both dates are synced. But, I *need* the timezone from the server.

Please advise, I'm out of ideas

Comment: I'm a little confused where you're having a problem here.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Are you trying to get everything set to UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 0));
```

`h` != `H` in date. It is 7pm, and you're trying to get the time from 1969-12-31 07:00:00am after.

Comment: Good catch. Thank you. It wasn't what I was looking for but I figured it out.

Comment: My issue was: I was trying to add 21 days using `echo strtotime('2010-11-05') +  60 * 60 * 24 * 21;` but this doesn't deal with the daylight saving time (which ends in November 7). So, when the date was converted, it returned 2010-11-25 23:00:00 instead of 2010-11-26.

Comment: the strtotime('2010-11-05 +21 days') fixed it

Comment: @hbt: that is why it is important to ask your **actual** question ;-)